# Can I use HTML5 cache manifest to improve performance for non-cached pages

Tags: iphone, html, mobile

We are building a mobile site and are seeing some sluggish performance on the iPhone. We believe part of the problem is that the iphone is not caching anything, due to the 25KB limitation (iPhone won't cache anything bigger than 25KB).

I have learned that the HTML 5 cache manifest can be used to cache static resources for offline use. Does anyone know if this same technique can be used to cache static resources (JS, CSS) for use on non-cached pages? I am getting conflicting answers here.

This article seems to claim that you can use this technique: http://www.phpied.com/iphone-caching/

Ben Nadel claims that non-cached pages cannot access resources in the cache manifest: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1946-Non-Cached-Pages-Cannot-Access-Resources-Cached-In-The-Cache-Manifest.htm

So my question is, can I utilize the cache manifest to improve performance? Will this work on an iphone?

Comment: Note that the second link discusses **only** Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ceejay is correct, the second link only discusses firefox and if you look at the first link it also mentions that it won't work in firefox. This technique will work with iphones, we use it on our site!